# change the value in the list with getx, the value is updated, but the screen does not rerender

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When i change the value in the list with getx, the value is updated, but the screen does not rerender.

i use GetBuilder because wrapping with obx gives an error.

But it still doesn't work where am I making a mistake

my controller:

```
 RxList<NotificationControl> notificationControlList =
      <NotificationControl>[].obs;

  void checkBoxChange(bool value, int index) {
    notificationControlList[index].isChecked = value;
    update();
  }
```

my view:

```
class NotificationCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  NotificationCheckbox({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<NotificationController>(
      id: "notification-cbx",
      // autoRemove: false, 
      // init: NotificationController(),
      builder: (logic) {
        return Checkbox(
          value: logic.notificationControlList[index].isChecked,
          onChanged: (bool? value) {
            logic.checkBoxChange(value ?? false, index);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

i use GetBuilder because wrapping with obx gives an error:

```
  [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected. 
  You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
  If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx 
  or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update 
  (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
  If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
```

Comment: The error you are getting is pretty self-explanatory. It looks like you don't have any reactive (Rx) variable under the Obx widget. After that try to refresh the rxlist by using list.refresh() function.

Comment: the list I want to update: RxList<NotificationControl> notificationControlList =
      <NotificationControl>[].obs;

Comment: Trying replacing notificationControlList[index].isChecked = value;
with notificationControlList[index].isChecked(value).
It might help

Comment: And replace logic.notificationControlList[index].isChecked with
logic.notificationControlList[index].isChecked.value.isTrue

Comment: I have used Getx alot but not familiar with getbuilder in obs we update values with () brackets and listen those under Obx() widget.

Comment: it doesn't work. But still, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oops. Most welcome. I am trying to run your code. Will update if get some better result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the contents of `notificationControlList` are being mutated outside the scope of GetX observers. The list doesn't know the items are being mutated. The way to make it work is to assign the changed item to the list in the same index. It's going to be like the below code snippet:

```dart
class NotificationController extends GetxController {
  RxList<NotificationControl> notificationControlList =
      <NotificationControl>[].obs;

  void checkBoxChange(bool value, int index) {
    notificationControlList[index].isChecked = value;
    notificationControlList[index] = notificationControlList[index];   // <- Just assign
    update();
  }
}
```

A better alternative though is to make `NotificationControl` immutable so this error never happens again. Make it like the following (assuming the properties `title` and `isChecked`):

```
class NotificationControl {
  final String title;
  final bool isChecked;
  const NotificationControl({required this.title, required this.isChecked});

  NotificationControl copyWith({bool? isChecked, String? title}) {
    return NotificationControl(
      title: title ?? this.title,
      isChecked: isChecked ?? this.isChecked,
    );
  }
}
```

The `copyWith` serves to clone the `NotificationControl` changing just the needed properties. The controller now looks like this:

```dart
class NotificationController extends GetxController {
  RxList<NotificationControl> notificationControlList =
      <NotificationControl>[].obs;

  void checkBoxChange(bool value, int index) {
    notificationControlList[index] =
        notificationControlList[index].copyWith(isChecked: value);
    update();
  }
}
```

Comment: When I use the answer you gave, when I wrap the widget with obx, it does not give an error and it works. Thank you so much. you are flutter expert